# android application sound for free

Tags: android, audio

I am writing an android application where providing some sound(wmv). I wanted to know, any sites which provides free sound files.  or i should buy the licence, please help.

sorry if this question is not meant to be here.

Thanks

Comment: what kind of sounds are you searching for?

Comment: wav short files..like click/ding/boing/..etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to name a few:

- http://freemusicarchive.org/
- http://www.freesound.org/

Comment: is this realy free...means i can use these files in my app and upload my app in android market ?

Comment: yes it is really free. you need to have some conditions met but it is free. everything is described there.

Answer (score 0):

also http://www.pacdv.com/sounds/

Comment: is this realy free...means i can use these files in my app and upload my app in android market ?

Comment: Make sure to read the documents and license agreements there may something in there where you have to put it in the about screens and such.

Comment: here is the Terms of use 
...
TERMS OF USE: You may use the sound effects on this web site free of charge in your video, film, audio and multimedia productions but DO NOT re-sell or re-license these sounds to anyone else, post on a web site for download, or link directly to individual sound files. If you use these sound effects, please consider linking back to this site but you don't have to.